# DATE - Normalization, a multiple ranged query, multiple inserts, and a multiple update

Tags: mysql, database, date, date-range, database-normalization

I have a booking system, airbnb style.

**TABLES -> prices, house, available_date.**

A house has available days and not available, but sometimes the days have different prices, a weekend is more expensive for example.

What are my options for storing the days: available, not available? If a house can have up to 366 information days.

**FIRST alternative** was to build **columns** with the information **startSaleDate**, **endSaleDate**. What in my opinion may be a choice of low performance of search, Because, when a day in the range is sale, we have to reprogram the house row, and has a possibility to be available a day on, a day off, generating 366 rows for 1 house!

But there is no other alternative? as a Normalization dates, or algorithms?

I'm not really finding anything that might help me out the mentioned problem...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? (Btw: why do you think having 366 rows for one house would be a problem?)

Comment: Im using MYSQL. with about 50 000 houses, has 50 000 * 366 = 18 300 000 values. and the search for homes involving dates available would be the main part of the system, I think it would be slow... @a_horse_with_no_name